# How could I order first 10 fields from one scope and join it with another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had two scopes which described users posts and admins posts. In my project I want to display in index controller first 10 admins posts and then an ActiveRecord Relation of last admins and users posts ordered by updated_at :desc

So this is my scopes I want to display:

```
scope :admins, -> { joins(:user).where('users.role = ?', '1') }
scope :users_and_approved, -> { joins(:user).where('users.role = ? AND approved = ?', '0', true) }
```

And method that combines them:

```
def self.index_services
  admins = Service.admins.order({ updated_at: :desc })
  users = Service.users_and_approved.order({ updated_at: :desc })
  admins.or(users)
end
```

But it returnes an ActiveRecord::Relation with ordering all fields without grouping them. What should SQL query look like to get first 10 posts from :admins and then list all last posts from :admins (from id = 11) and all posts from :users_and_approved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I recommend you using more modern syntax for ActiveRecord

```
scope :admins, -> { joins(:user).where(users: { role: '1' }) }
scope :users_and_approved, -> { joins(:user).where(approved: true, users: { role: '0'}) }
```

It is hard to satisfy all your conditions and make only one request.
I'd rather do it like:

```
def self.index_services
  admins = Service.admins.first(10) # first 10 posts from :admins
  admins_last = Service.admins.where.not(id: admins.map(&:id)) # all last posts from :admins (from id = 11)
  users = Service.users_and_approved.order(updated_at: :desc)
  admins + admins_last + users
end
```

or even

```
admins + admins_last.or(users)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't use a "+" method because of kaminari gem, that don't work with Array that creates after "+" method. That is only thing I should use ActiveRecord::Relation class

Comment: I think I should find a solution for kaminari and make it work with Array. Anyway, your solution is slight perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @3kpvc main problem is with `first 10` condition. You can get the same result with `admins = Service.admins.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(10)` at it would be ActiveRecord::Relation, but i'm not sure if it would work with `.or` (it didn't work on my env due to DB restrictions). But you can still try it on your env.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`take`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/take) and [`offset`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset) methods of ActiveRecord

Maybe something like this:

```
def self.index_services
  admins = Service.admins.order({ updated_at: :desc }).take(10)
  remaining_admins = Service.admins.order({ updated_at: :desc }).offset(10)
  users = Service.users_and_approved.order({ updated_at: :desc })
  admins + remaining_admins.or(users)
end
```